# Separate string into table of words and spaces between

Tags: lua, lua-table, lua-patterns

I am currently working on a lua script that takes in a string and separates it into a table of words and the spaces + characters between the words.

Example:

```
-- convert this
local input = "This string, is a text!"

-- to this
local output = {
    "This", " ", "string", ", ", "is", " ", "a", " ", "text", "!"
}
```

I tried solving this with lua's pattern implementation, but wasn't successful so far.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `local output={}; for w in input:gsub("%f[%w].-%f[^%w]","\0%0\0"):gmatch"%Z+" do table.insert(output, w) end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
local function splitter(input)
  local result = {}
  for non_word, word, final_non_word in input:gmatch "([^%w]*)(%w+)([^%w]*)" do
    if non_word ~= '' then
      table.insert(result, non_word)
    end
    table.insert(result, word)
    if final_non_word ~= '' then
      table.insert(result, final_non_word)
    end
  end
  return result
end
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer. It seems to work perfectly fine, except for strings which start with a `non_word`, eg. an ellipsis. Any way to capture that too?